# Select option list not showing Selected attribute value when navigation is done

Tags: html, jquery

As you can see that i have 3 items in navbar on click of each i will get a list of items. I am using select options to filter the values shown in list.

Initially i will be in  "My list" navbar and do some filter and then i will click on "My AG List" navbar option and i will do select some option to filter that list .. then if i come back to "My List" the option that was selected in "My AG List" will be shown in "My List"... Here how can i show the selected attribute value that i have given in options.

```
<div data-role="navbar">
                <ul id="ulmainnav">
                    <li><a href="#ListAssignee" id="mylistcount" class="ui-btn-active" onclick="ListIMAssignee();" data-theme="c" data-prefetch="true">My List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ListAssignment" id="myaglistcount" data-prefetch="true" onclick="ListIMAssignment();" data-theme="c">My AG List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ListHour" id="lasthourcount" onclick="ListIMHour();" data-theme="c" data-prefetch="true">Last Hour</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" id="ListAssignee">
                <table id="assigneefilter">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" width="100%">Select Filter</td>
                            <td>
                                <select data-mini="true" onchange="CallFilterAssignee(this.value)" id="selectassigneefilter">
                                    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Status</option>
                                    <option>Open</option>
                                    <option>Work In Progress</option>
                                    <option>Pending Customer</option>
                                    <option>Accepted</option>
                                </select>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <ul id="IMListAssignee" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
                <ul id="IMListAssigneeFilter" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" id="ListAssignment">
                <table id="assignmentfilter">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" width="100%">Select Filter</td>
                            <td>
                                <select data-mini="true" onchange="CallFilterAssignment(this.value)" id="selectassignmentfilter">
                                    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Status</option>
                                    <option>Open</option>
                                    <option>Work In Progress</option>
                                    <option>Pending Customer</option>
                                    <option>Accepted</option>
                                </select>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <ul id="IMListAssignment" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
                <ul id="IMListAssignmentFilter" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: I have tried using #("selectassignmentfilter").selectmenu("refresh"); option when i will call respective function when option is selected.

Comment: Did you mean after navigating to a different link you don't see the selected one, what did you mean by after come back ?

Comment: i am in "My List" and it shows me the list of items under it and i have select option filter to filter(will select Open from options) to show only specific items in the list that i select from select options.. then i click on "My Ag List" and in that list also i will do some filter (will select Accepted) from the select options. And after this when i again click back to "My List", "Accepted" option will be shown in the select filter .. Here i need the selected attribute value (<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Status</option>) that i have given.